# Center brand in jquery slicknav

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to place a brand in slick nav and have it center to the div vertically.

```
$('#menu').slicknav({
  init: function() {
    $('.mobile_currency').detach().appendTo($('.slicknav_nav'));
  },
  prependTo: '#mobile_nav',
  brand: '<div style="background-color: #efefef; width: 60%; height: 55px; float: right;"><img style="width: 100px; float: right; " src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0519/6401/t/23/assets/cl.logo.jpg?v=1588268959"></div>',
  label: '<div aria-haspopup="true" role="navigation" aria-label="'+ Shopify.translation.menu +'"><span class="icon-menu"></span> '+ Shopify.translation.menu +'</div>',
  closedSymbol: '<span class="icon-right-arrow menu-icon" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></span>',
  openedSymbol: '<span class="icon-down-arrow menu-icon" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"></span>',
  allowParentLinks: true,
  nestedParentLinks: false,
});
```

The relevant part would be this:

```
brand: '<div style="background-color: #efefef; width: 60%; height: 55px; float: right;"><img style="width: 100px; float: right; " src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.jpg"></div>',
```

The image appears on the right side of the gray div area.  How can I get it to be centered vertically?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `display: flex;` and then `align-items: center;`?

Comment: It worked, thank you!  @JoelHager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `display: flex;` and then `align-items: center;`?